# Does this phone charger circuit meet the USB port's 1 A current rating safely?

Tags: transformer, charger, output, step-down, usb-host

[image]

Vp = 170 V; Vrms= 120 V.

I'm using a 9-0-9 1 A step-down transformer, a full-wave bridge rectifier, a 1000 μF capacitor, and an 800 Ω resistance to convert the input voltage to 7.4 V approximately.

The LM7805 has a 2 V dropout voltage in order to regulate 5 V on its output, and I use a 0,01 μF capacitor to lessen voltage variations (or so I'm told). The I-O differential voltage is meant to be between 2-3 V, with 2.5 V being the optimal value.

VBUS receives 5 V, D+ receives 3 V  and D- receives 2 V.

I want to build this circuit for prolonged use, so I will also design the PCB and have it fabricated later on. But before that, I must be certain that I will not accidentally cause the USB port to overheat because it isn't getting enough current. Also, no, I did not come up with this myself, I am using someone else's diagram as reference.

Comment: If you have a 9-0-9 transformer, you can use a two-diode rectifier. What's the point of the 800 ohm resistor, just to lower the power dissipation in the 7805? I wouldn't use a 7805 here at all.

Comment: What is the purpose of building this? Is it just a learning exercise? There are off the shelf parts to make this a _lot_ simpler and more efficient (also of course off the shelf USB chargers). Nobody builds linear regulators with huge transformers for USB anymore.

Comment: I have to develop a product proposal for one of my college classes,  it has to be related to my career (systems engineering) in a valid capacity. Naturally, i coudn't come up with anything so i am grasping at straws here. That would explain the nonpractical diagram you had to misfortune of seeing. This is not my preferred field, so you can expect more nonsense like this from me if i have to continue with this.

Comment: @IsmaelPárica Don't be too hard on yourself! This _can_ be made workable, although it'll be inefficient and run hot. Or you can look online for modern switching (SMPS) designs - search term would be "offline smps 5v." There are plenty out there. Either way you'll learn a lot. Just be careful with mains voltages. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

No, that will destroy any device connected to it, because data pin D+ is connected to 5V supply.

If the input is 7V and output is 5V, at 1A current the regulator must dissipate 2W, which makes it heat up a lot, approximately 50 degrees higher than ambient.

So while in theory this circuit could be a 1A charger, it is not very practical.

Comment: I feared as much. Well, i suppose i should get rid of it and reproduce a proprietary design.

Answer (score 1):

The 800 ohm resistor makes no sense.  You're never going to get 1 amp through that.  My off the top of my head estimate is that it would need to be more like 3.5 ohms to get the voltages you show.

Also, with the resistor between the reservoir capacitor and the 7805, you no longer have the capacitor on the 7805's input that the data sheet recommends.

Comment: Good points. I did not even bother to check the sanity of those parts. 1A through 800 ohms needs 800 volts.

Comment: Good to know. I'll have to get rid of the diagram and start with a proprietary design. Any one of them will be several times preferable to this pile of garbage.